Can I Integrate a Third-Party SDK in Flutter if It's Unavailable on pub.dev?
I'm attempting to integrate the TikTok SDK into my Flutter project specifically for Android. However, I'm encountering difficulties when trying to install the TikTok SDK directly into my Flutter project. The version available on pub.dev is outdated, so I opted to integrate it manually. Here's what I've done so far:
In my app/build.gradle file, I've added the following dependencies:
dependencies {
implementation 'com.tiktok.open.sdk:tiktok-open-sdk-core:2.3.0'
implementation 'com.tiktok.open.sdk:tiktok-open-sdk-auth:2.3.0'
implementation 'com.tiktok.open.sdk:tiktok-open-sdk-share:2.3.0'
}

And I've included the TikTok SDK repository in the build.gradle file:
repositories { google() mavenCentral()  maven { url "``https://artifact.bytedance.com/repository/AwemeOpenSDK``" } }

Despite these configurations, I'm encountering an error when attempting to run my app.
I'm facing the following error:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* `What went wrong:`
  `Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugAssets'.`

> `Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.`
> `Could not find com.tiktok.open.sdk:tiktok-open-sdk-core:2.3.0,com.tiktok.open.sdk:tiktok-open-sdk-auth:2.3.0 and Could not find com.tiktok.open.sdk:tiktok-open-sdk-share:2.3.0. Searched in the following locations:`
> ``` - ``https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/tiktok/open/sdk/tiktok-open-sdk-core/2.3.0/tiktok-open-sdk-core-2.3.0.pom ```
> ``` - ``https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/tiktok/open/sdk/tiktok-open-sdk-core/2.3.0/tiktok-open-sdk-core-2.3.0.pom ```
> ``` - ``https://storage.googleapis.com/download.flutter.io/com/tiktok/open/sdk/tiktok-open-sdk-core/2.3.0/tiktok-open-sdk-core-2.3.0.pom ```
> ``` - ``https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/tiktok/open/sdk/tiktok-open-sdk-core/2.3.0/tiktok-open-sdk-core-2.3.0.pom ```
> ``` - ``https://www.jitpack.io/com/tiktok/open/sdk/tiktok-open-sdk-core/2.3.0/tiktok-open-sdk-core-2.3.0.pom ```
> `Required by: project :app`

Could someone please guide me through the correct process of integrating the TikTok SDK into a Flutter project for Android? Additionally, are there any common pitfalls or additional steps I might be missing during the integration process?

Welcome to Stack Overflow! I made an attempt at cleaning up the formatting issues, but I think I've missed some backticks in your error message. Please repost your error message and wrap it in triple backticks, as I've done, so that it is readable. See [the guide on formatting[(/help/formatting) for more information.

You would follow the instructions to create a plugin package here: https://docs.flutter.dev/packages-and-plugins/developing-packages. If there's an existing plugin (even if out of date) try using it, even if you have to clone and update it yourself. That way you'll either successfully update the existing package or learn enough to create your own (if the existing one is truly beyond repair).
